# Calculate indexPath then reload Data? Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing, reload

Hey guys I have a situation I can't quite wrap my head around. How would I calculate the indexPath of a Segued View Controller? When I segue over from my `CollectionViewCell` I get the index data from the cell. so far so good.

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let sales: Sales!
    let tSale: [Sale] = revenueData.tSale
        sales = tSales[indexPath.row]
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailedView", sender: sales)
    }  
}
```

`

Now, I need to reload the data to present information from the next indexPath from within the second View controller. I think I might need to grab the indexPath data it has to reload into another index. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hook in `UIViewController` for configuring the new view controller before it’s displayed. Something like this might work.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailedView", sender: (sales, indexPath.row))
```

and then

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard
        let sender = sender,
        let (sale, row) = sender as? (Sale, Int)
        else { return }

    segue.destination.sale = sale
    segue.destination.saleIndex = row
}
```